# Adding Custom Login Flow for Liferay Portal 7.4.3

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

I have a requirement to customize the authentication flow of the Liferay. I have to authenticate users by calling an external API with username and password after that I have to invoke Liferay's open Id connect authentication (Azure AD) as the secondary authentication via code to get the user authenticated with some state parameters. I have followed below URL for creating the Custom Login Portlet.

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017882592-Writing-a-Custom-Login-Portlet-

After deploying the custom login portlet, the portal is still showing the default Sign In form on clicking the Sign In button.

1. Someone already integrated similar scenario, please share how we can configure or deploy the above-mentioned Custom Login Portlet in liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.70-ga70 bundle.
2. Is it possible to invoke OpenId authentication via code after primary login?